# How to use equirectangular projection in TileMill?

Tags: dictionary, map-projections, tilemill

I need to get an equirectangular projected map out of TileMill (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection).

I found a tutorial online explaining how to get a different projection by altering the project's setting in the 'project.mml' file.
(http://blog.kartena.se/using-tilemill-without-spherical-mercator/)

And I found what I thought to be a description of the necessary srs code for an equirectangular projection:

```
"srs": "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs"
```

However, the map no just shows a long thin line of water, nothing else, so clearly that's not quire right.
I've been scouring for more detail about how to set this up but I'm totally stumped.
The Web Mercator projection is no good for my purposes.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks so much.

S

Answer (score 1):

This won't be possible in TileMill itself: the software is designed to output Spherical Mercator tiles only. Your best option would be to export [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org/) XML from TileMill, modify it to support `EPSG:4326`, and then serve the tiles from something like [TileStache](http://tilestache.org/).